# How to automatically add text in listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

Here is my code:

```
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        lvFabric.Items.Item(0).Text = txtFind.Text
    End If
```

The code above is only specifying where the text should be added in the listview.

The flow of the whole function is first there is a textbox(txtFind),for example the user will input a text then press enter, after the user press enter the text will be added in the listview. the user will do this 3 times, what I want is how to automatically add text in listview without specifying the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
  lvFabric.Items.add(New ListViewItem(txtFind.Text))
End If
```